# Get everything after the hash tag # in url

Tags: javascript, php, hashtag

I have a url like this `http://example.com/?hello=1234`

using this

```
   ob_start();
   var_dump($_GET);
   $result = ob_get_clean();
   print_r($result);
```

i get this

```
 array(1) {
 ["hello"]=>
 string(3) "123"
 }
```

but when it comes to `http://example.com/#hello=1234` im getting nothing. 
i know that # is for client side/browser but is there any way to get everything after the # (hash tag) ?

Answer (score 3):

The URL fragment is not sent to the server at all.

You can access it in client-side Javascript using `location.hash`.

Comment: i tried something like this but i is empty `<script>alert(window.location.hash);</script>`

Answer (score 0):

`var hash = location.hash.slice(1)` in JavaScript will get you everything after the #.

For `http://example.com/#hello=1234` var hash would be hello=1234

Answer (score -2):

You either have to parse the url using [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/function.parse-url.php) or use javascript instead `window.location.hash`

Comment: @AbraCadaver be more constructive in your answers before downvoting